# how to move an image according to the xy coordinates that we get from a wifi signal in android

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, wifi

Wi-Fi trilateration measures the signal intensity to determine user location X Y coordinates i want to use that coordinates to move an image is it possible.

this is my first project i'm newbie to android

Comment: can you tell me how it can be done that would be much help

Comment: which part are you having problems with? What is the current status of your project? Code samples will help

Comment: currently i can get the user position coordinates and i want to use them to show the user location as an image overlay on the map

Comment: If you edit your question to focus more on the specific problem you are having trouble with you're more likely to get help.
Be clear with what it is you are trying to achieve, what you have tried and what you don't understand. 
Use minimal code samples to illustrate the above.